# Is this potential policy question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Before I invest time into getting sources and asking a well defined question, I want to make sure this question is on topic.

I saw this [BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-44725026) describing how six figure salaries in San Francisco are classified as low income with the following passage:

> In San Francisco, high rents have driven the government's "low income" threshold of $117,400 (£87,970) almost as high as the median income for a family of four in the area - $118,400 (£88,630).
>
> While falling below this mark does not automatically entitle families
>   to government housing assistance such as subsidies and public housing,
>   it is a factor that is considered.

I want to know more about this, specifically my question would be something like "Are any people who make over $100,000 getting housing benefits?" But fleshed out with prior research and well defined.

Is this on topic? I think it is, because it is a descriptive question about the effect of policy, but [other](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2721/are-questions-about-the-demographics-of-who-benefits-from-a-policy-on-topic) similar [questions](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/nuts-and-bolts-policy-questions-are-getting-migrated) are sometimes closed as off topic or sent to Law.stackexchange or personal-finance.stackexchange (where they are usually ignored).

Comment: With that formulation and source you might try skeptics.

Answer (score 3):

If your question was:

> Are people who make $117,400 in San Francisco getting government housing benefits?

The I'd probably leave it open.  I'd assume that most other people would too.

---

If your question is

> I want to know more about this

It would be closed for being too broad

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this question is on-topic because it is not really a question about politics and political processes. Sure, who gets housing benefits and who doesn't is the result of political decisions some politicians made for some reasons through some political processes. But this applies to quite a lot of aspects of daily life.

I think essentially this is a question about finances. Sure, your internal motivation for asking this question in the first place might be political, but that doesn't change the question. An expert in personal finances and money would be able to give you a much more competent answer about who is eligible for housing benefits and who isn't than an expert in politics.

That's why I would recommend to ask this particular question on https://money.stackexchange.com.

Tipp: Money.SE is more of a personal advise site. Helpful answers might be more likely if you frame it as a question from someone who is personally affected and not from someone who has an academic interest in the matter.

Comment: From our Help: "...asking about the tangible benefits and costs of legislation is on topic". The number of people receiving assistance from a public program is an example of the benefits/costs of a policy.